# Is it necessary to Test the DAO classes when i already tested the Facade with Junit?

Tags: service, junit, dao, facade

im currently testing  my JSF Webapplication which is based on this Tutorial. 
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/full-web-application-tomcat-jsf.html
the Facade controlls the Transaction with the DAO Methods.

How would a DAO JUnit Test look like? Do i even have to test them when i test the Facade? 
This is an example how i tested the Facade Methods

Thx for your help!

```
@Test
public void newUserTest() {
    User user = new User ();
    userDAO.beginTransaction();
    user.setUsername("Test");
    user.setPassword("123");
    userDAO.save(user);

    User user 2 = adminDAO.findUserWithUsername(admin.getUsername());

    assertEquals("Test", user2.getUsername());

    userDAO.rollback();
    userDAO.closeTransaction(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to write the test for the DAO. It's more of integration testing with the database. Its always better to have a test for each line of code.

Ideally, in Facade, it should be a unit test where you will just verify if the DAO is called with correct parameters.